# Mouse can't reach screen corners after update to 17.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, mouse, 17.10

My info:
Dell Latitude d630 (32-bit)
Memory: 2.0
Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T8300 @ 2.40GHz × 2 
Graphic card: nVidia Quadro NVS 135M/PCIe/SSE2 (128mb)

I've used Ubuntu 16.04 on my Laptop for a good couple of months. So, today I decided to upgrade to 17.10. 
Everything went fine until I restarted the machine and before logging in, the mouse pointer wasn't visible,  so I restarted the machine at least 3 time before it's visible.
But the pointer still doesn't move NORMALLY; It's tied to the middle of screen, whenever I move toward corners, it reaches a certain point and stops, and when I touch it to start moving it goes back to the middle of screen.

*I wish my description is accurate, I can record a video if you like!

*And I'm not a very technical user so please consider this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What make and model of mouse?

Answer (score 0):

After having some good time outdoors. Finally, the issue has been solved by selecting disabled repositories sources in `Software & Updates> Other software` and run the upgrade + restart the machine.

All that was because the Upgrade hasn't finished yet so some drivers were not working properly. Also, you may not have this issue with Usb-mouse it's just on Touchpad.

Cheers!